# Minify javascript/css on an embedded device, cannot introduce toolchains

Tags: javascript, minify, bundling-and-minification

I am running a web server on an embedded device using Wt and it is a javascript heavy site. I use a chroot environment for compiling, making the package (deb-based), and installing. I need a way to minify the javascript/css without using third-party tools (uglify requires NodeJS, npm, Java) where I can use CMAKE and call a command line executable to do it for me. I found a few shell scripts (perl, bash) but when minified my javascript had a lot of unexplainable errors.

What's on my stack:

- perl 5.8.8
- bash 3.2.39
- python 2.7.5
- No Java

Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks!

**What I have tried:**

- https://github.com/Aralhach/bashobfus/tree/master. Code does not minify like uglify, just removes tabs and spacing, no one-line minify. Don't know perl to fix this.
- YUI uses java - cant use
- Uglify uses node - cant use
- closure-compiler (minifier) uses java - cant use
- sed script - some reason nuking my javascript syntax and causes errors

Comment: I would help if you could mention what you have tried and how that didn't work.

Comment: Why do you need to do that on the device? For our server we minimize code and styles in the deployment step before pushing them on the server. We also do code validation and unit testing right after the minimization to be sure nothing went wrong there.

Comment: We have a flag in our build process which can have the following option: -- [DEVELOPMENT|TESTING|PRODUCTION]. In development we don't compress it during the build, sometimes in testing we minify it depending on the situation, and always minify in production.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://www.tero.co.uk/scripts/minify.php) for example?

Comment: @Lars, unfortunately that doesn't seem to be good enough for production. Will keep scp-ing, yui-compressing and scp-ing back again my files until a non-Java version of yui (or another pro compressor) is available :'(

Answer (score 0):

do you have the ability to run perl? I'm not sure if it's executable from cmake (that's what I'm searching for information on now) but I have been using minified web content to save into flash memory when building esp8266 web content. I built a script using CPAN libraries to minify html, css and javascript and put them into a .h header file I can read from my main code.

I put the web files under a www structure then map the minified stuff under a /gz/ sub dir with the directory specifying the type. (e.g. gz/htm, gz/js, gz/css) that my server then sends with the appropriate encoding and url translation. Most browsers support gzip'd content and it allows me to send web content much faster from an embedded device.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CSS::Packer;
use JavaScript::Packer;
use HTML::Packer;
use File::Slurp;
use Gzip::Faster;
use MIME::Types;


my $outfile = "src/webfiles.h";
my $webdir = "www";
my $find_exe = "/usr/bin/find";
my $xxdexe = "/usr/bin/xxd -i";
my $findcmd = $find_exe . " " . $webdir . " -type f ";

my $mt = MIME::Types->new();
my $files = open(FINDSTRM, "$findcmd|") || die $!;
my @filelist;
while($line = <FINDSTRM>) {
   chomp($line);
   if($line =~ /^$webdir(.*)\/([^\.\/]+)\.(\w{2,4})$/) {
      my %fileinfo;
      $fileinfo{path} = "$1/$2.$3";
      $fileinfo{dir} = $1;
      $fileinfo{name} = $2;
      $fileinfo{ext} = $3;
      my $type =  $mt->mimeTypeOf($fileinfo{ext});
      $fileinfo{type} = $type->{MT_type};

      my $bindat;
      if($type->{MT_type} eq "text/html") {
         print "html minifying $line\n";
         my $html = read_file($line);
         my $packer = HTML::Packer->init();
         my $htmin = $packer->minify( \$html, { remove_newlines => 1, remove_comments => 1, do_javascript => 'best', do_stylesheet => 'minify' } ); 
         $bindat = gzip($htmin);
      }
      if($type->{MT_type} eq "text/css") {
         print "css minifying $line\n";
         my $css = read_file($line);
         my $packer = CSS::Packer->init();
         my $cssmin = $packer->minify(\$css, { compress => 'minify', remove_comments => 1 } );
         $bindat = gzip($cssmin);
      }
      if($type->{MT_type} eq "application/javascript") {
         print "javascript minifying $line\n";
         my $js = read_file($line);
         my $packer = JavaScript::Packer->init();
         my $jsmin = $packer->minify(\$js, { compress => 'best', remove_comments => 1, remove_copyright => 1 } );
         $bindat = gzip($jsmin);
      }

      # other text based formats
      if( $type->{MT_type} eq "text/plain" ) {
         print "compressing text in $line\n";
         my $asc = read_file($line);
         $bindat = gzip($asc);
      }

      if(length($bindat) == 0) {
         print "raw reading $line\n";
         $bindat = read_file($line, { binmode => ':raw' });
         $fileinfo{enc} = '';
      } else {
         $fileinfo{enc} = 'gzip';
      }

      {
         use bytes;
         $fileinfo{len} = length($bindat);
      }
      $tfile = "/tmp/tmpfile";
      write_file( $tfile, {binmode => ':raw'}, $bindat );
      open(INXXD, "$xxdexe < $tfile |") || die $!;
      $fileinfo{hexdat} = do { local $/; <INXXD> };
      close INXXD;
      $fileinfo{hexdat} =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
      push(@filelist,\%fileinfo);
  }
}
close FINDSTRM;

open(OUTFILE, ">", $outfile) || die $!;
print OUTFILE "\n#include \"Flash.h\"\n\n";

$count = 1;
foreach $f (@filelist) {
   print OUTFILE "FLASH_ARRAY(uint8_t, file_" . $count . ",\n";
   print OUTFILE "  " . $f->{hexdat};
   print OUTFILE ");\n\n";
   $count++;
}

print OUTFILE "struct t_websitefiles {\n";
print OUTFILE "  const char* path;\n";
print OUTFILE "  const char* mime;\n";
print OUTFILE "  const unsigned int len;\n";
print OUTFILE "  const char* enc;\n";
print OUTFILE "  const _FLASH_ARRAY<uint8_t>* content;\n";
print OUTFILE "} files[] = {\n";

$count = 1;
foreach $f (@filelist) {
   print OUTFILE "  {\n";
   print OUTFILE "    .path = \"" . $f->{path} . "\",\n";
   print OUTFILE "    .mime = \"" . $f->{type} . "\",\n";
   print OUTFILE "    .len = " . $f->{len} . ",\n";
   print OUTFILE "    .enc = \"" . $f->{enc} . "\",\n";
   print OUTFILE "    .content = \&file_" . $count . ",\n";
   print OUTFILE "  },\n";
   $count++;
}

print OUTFILE "};\n";
close OUTFILE;
```